# Процент от числа с помощью case

Tags: plsql

Как получить в результат `f10=0,0%`, если f9=`null` и в `f1=19`.
В f10 считается по формуле `f9/f1 * 100`

В представленной выдержки из запроса

Если в `f9` в результате `null` то в f10 получается `,0%`. А нужно `0,0%`.
В других вариантах получается как надо, например:

если в `f1=10`, `f9=10` то в `f10=100%`;
если в `f1=19`, `f9=11` то в `f10=57,9%`.

Выдержка из запроса

```
...
    case 
    when instr(to_char(ROUND(f9/(f1),3) * 100),',') > 0 then to_char(ROUND(f9/(f1),3) * 100) 
    else to_char(ROUND(f9/(f1),3) * 100)|| ',0' 
    End ||'%' f10
...
```

Comment: *если f9=пусто* ?? какой тип поля? что такое "пусто" на самом деле - NULL?

Comment: Тип поля VARCHAR2(255). Да пусто - null

Comment: Ну тогда просто конвертируйте этот NULL в, скажем, `'0.0'`. Функцией COALESCE().

Comment: А такой вариант не рассматривали?:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3e2ba9c889c95277d1527f1137e6d0bc